# StoryBook addon-docs: "No props found for this component" using TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, storybook

I have an issue with a project based on TypeScript and StoryBook:

Table with component properties is not created and visible in StoryBook "Docs" tab on a project setup with TypeScript.

And a text ""No props found for this component" is shown instead (please look at screenshot attached).

I would need to show the table with listed the properties in this case "name".

What am I doing wrong in the setup?

[image]

**Code snippets**

Test.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react';

type TestProps = {
 /**
  * Description of prop "name".
  */
  name: string;
};

export function Test({ name }: TestProps) {
  return <div>{name}</div>;
}
```

Test.stories.tsx

```
import { storiesOf } from '@storybook/react';
import * as React from 'react';
import { Test } from './Test';

storiesOf('00_Test', module)
  .addParameters({ component: Test })
  .add('Test', () => <Test name="Hello world!" />);
```

**System:**

```
System:
    OS: macOS 10.15.4
    CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz
  Binaries:
    Node: 10.16.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.0/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.17.3 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
    npm: 6.14.4 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.0/bin/npm
  Browsers:
    Chrome: 83.0.4103.61
    Firefox: 76.0.1
    Safari: 13.1
  npmPackages:
    @storybook/addon-actions: ^5.3.19 => 5.3.19
    @storybook/addon-docs: ^5.3.19 => 5.3.19
    @storybook/addon-info: ^5.3.19 => 5.3.19
    @storybook/addon-knobs: ^5.3.19 => 5.3.19
    @storybook/addon-links: ^5.3.19 => 5.3.19
    @storybook/addon-storyshots: ^5.3.19 => 5.3.19
    @storybook/addons: ^5.3.19 => 5.3.19
    @storybook/react: ^5.3.19 => 5.3.19
    @storybook/theming: ^5.3.19 => 5.3.19
```

**Additional context**

package.json

```
"react": "^16.12.0",
"react-dom": "^16.12.0",
  "typescript": "^3.7.5"
```

.storybook/main.js

```
module.exports = {
  stories: ['../src/**/*.stories.tsx'],
  addons: [
    '@storybook/addon-actions/register',
    '@storybook/addon-knobs/register',
    '@storybook/addon-docs'
  ]
};
```

.storybook/webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = ({ config }) => {
  addons: [
    {
      name: '@storybook/addon-docs',
      options: {
        configureJSX: true,
        babelOptions: {},
        sourceLoaderOptions: null,
      },
    },
  ],
  config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: require.resolve("awesome-typescript-loader")
      },
    ]
  });
  config.resolve.extensions.push(".ts", ".tsx");
  return config;
};
```

Comment: It's not just you.  I eventually just gave up on trying to get this to work.  This was with as simple a TS project as I could do without deviating from the CRA TS template and as "stock" a StoryBook config I could do.  I'm not sure where the breakdown is.  It was also with the `storiesOf` API, not the MDX format.

Comment: @zero298 I definitely can understand your frustration, below a solution I found, I hope it can help you. If you still have problem please post a question and link here, I would be glad to help out :) ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue, basically I had misconfigured the `webpack.config.js` for StoryBook,

```
      {
        loader: require.resolve('react-docgen-typescript-loader'),
      },
```

I hope can help others.

Full version:

.storybook/webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = ({ config }) => {
  addons: [
    {
      name: '@storybook/addon-docs',
      options: {
        configureJSX: true,
        babelOptions: {},
        sourceLoaderOptions: null,
      },
    },
  ],
  config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: require.resolve("awesome-typescript-loader")
      },
      {
        loader: require.resolve('react-docgen-typescript-loader'),
      },
    ]
  });
  config.resolve.extensions.push(".ts", ".tsx");
  return config;
};
```

Comment: will it work if i have jsx file and corresponding d.ts file? I want to write some stories for a package that is published on npm. Since you can only publish npm packages with js files with d.ts files to types..i don't have the TS files to exract props data

Comment: @KaranGarg did you manage to do that? I have the exact need atm

Comment: @ChristopherFrancisco it was a while back and i seriously don't remember what i did back then.